# Subtracting a CSV List from Another?

Tags: excel, csv, numbers, seo

I have a huge list of broken links I generated with Screaming Frog and started to fix a lot of them.. I ran the csv file back through screaming frog to see which broken links I had left so now I have 2 CSV files.  How do I subtract the newer list from the old list so I can see which links I already fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function in Excel:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$6, A1), "Borked", "Fixed")
```

Just make sure that the A value points to something in the smaller list (still broken) and the B range covers the original set of broken links

Comment: Just note that this function will need to be run on every item in your list of still brokens links. (just drag the little black box in the corner of the cell, the $'s keep the B range from changing with the A value)

Answer (score 2):

The following method assumes:

A:  All broken links are in oldfile.
B:  Some broken links are in newfile.
C:  The shared lines are exact duplicates.

```
sort newfile oldfile | uniq -d > filesThatAreStillBroken
```

or

```
sort  newfile oldfile | uniq -u > filesThatAreFixed
```

Sort merges the files together into a single sorted list.  It doesn't matter if newfile or oldfile is first.

uniq -d puts out only lines that occur more than once.  Since they were in both lists, they are still broken.

uniq -u puts out only lines are are unique.

Note:  This won't catch new errors that you have introduced while fixing the old errors.  New errors will only be in newfiles and so will be falsely reported as fixed in the second invocation, and not reported at all in the first invocation.

Type

```
man sort
man uniq
```

for more details about these two command line utilities.

If you are on a windows box, you can install the cygwin environment, or possibly windows now has a posix command set.

Comment: I love Linux, I love bash!

Answer (score 1):

Import both CSV's into excel.

Add the formula into cells in column B of the larger list: `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A1)`

This will give you a count of how many times that cell appears in the other list.

Now you just have to delete any that have a count > 0.

Tip: To delete the rows easily: Add a header row, turn on auto filters, deselect count of 0, delete the rows, turn off auto filters.  (Alternatively, you could sort your list if you don't mind the order getting messed up)